# Advanced question list filtering

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, sorting, filtering

Is there a way to do filtering and sorting at the same time on the question pages?

For example, I want to view unanswered questions for all of my interest tags (the "My Tags" tab), but the default sorting is by upvotes, and I want to sort it by age (same as the "Newest" tab). I've tried messing with the URL, but without luck.

Comment: +1 - Would love to sort Unanswered "My Tags" by date

Comment: I would vote for this if I could...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you'd have to cracker jack your way into searching with the tags and the [custom search tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

So let's say your interest involves **`[cthulu]`**, **`[cerebus]`** and **`[green-tea]`** (because y'know, you like to relax as you read the great texts)

For those without any answers:

> answers:0 [cthulu] [cerebus] [green-tea]

For those that are still unaccepted and open, and pretty much unanswered:

> hasaccepted:0 [cthulu] [cerebus] [green-tea]

Search like that and you're on your way to winning with the tabs and sorting by tags. But if you've got about a dozen dozen eggs, then it could get a little unwieldy.

Comment: You, sir, are my hero. While it's ugly, I'll deal with it since it lets me see exactly what I want.